# Circular dependency exception when creating a custom logger relying on options with a options validator relying on a logger

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a .NET Core worker application and want to add a custom file logger since `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` does not provide this. I don't want to use an extra package for this (e.g. Serilog).

I put information about the log directory and log file into my options class. This options class also has a validator implementing the `IValidateOptions` interface. This validator gets injected a logger instance to log validation errors if some occured.

The file logger provider needs to get injected the options monitor to get access to the directory and file configurations.

When running the application I unfortunately get an exception

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be
> constructed'

with the content

> Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostApplicationLifetime Lifetime:
> Singleton ImplementationType:
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ApplicationLifetime': A circular
> dependency was detected for the service of type
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory'.
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostApplicationLifetime(Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ApplicationLifetime)
> -> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ApplicationLifetime>(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger<Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ApplicationLifetime>)
> -> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory)
> -> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerProvider>
> -> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerProvider(Ajifsdjfijgsidjfijsdifjisd.FileLoggerProvider)
> -> Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptionsMonitor<MyLib.MyOptions>(Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor<MyLib.MyOptions>)
> -> Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptionsFactory<MyLib.MyOptions>(Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory<MyLib.MyOptions>)
> -> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IValidateOptions<MyLib.MyOptions>>
> -> Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IValidateOptions<MyLib.MyOptions>(MyLib.MyOptionsValidator)
> -> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IValidateOptions<MyLib.MyOptions>>(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger<Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IValidateOptions<MyLib.MyOptions>>)
> -> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory

This makes sense because when injecting a new logger instance this one gets injected the options. And these will trigger the validator which gets injected a new logger instance. And so it starts again.

> Logger => Options => Validator => Logger => Options => Validator =>
> Logger => Options => Validator => ...

I don't know how to solve this problem because my file logger needs to get access to the configuration options and my options validator should log validation errors.

Any ideas?

---

If you want to get an overview about the application, this is what I did to reproduce it:

- Create a new .NET Core Worker project
- Head over to the .csproj file and add `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />` to the first item group to gain access to Kestrel and the web stuff
- I add a library `MyLib` to the project and reference it in the main project
- In the library I create a options class holding the information for the file logger

.

```
public class MyOptions
{
    public string DirectoryPath { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

- I also add a simple options validator sample which makes use of a logger instance

.

```
public class MyOptionsValidator : IValidateOptions<MyOptions>
{
    private readonly ILogger<IValidateOptions<MyOptions>> logger;

    public MyOptionsValidator(ILogger<IValidateOptions<MyOptions>> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public ValidateOptionsResult Validate(string name, MyOptions myOptions)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myOptions.DirectoryPath) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(myOptions.FileName))
        {
            logger.LogWarning("Invalid");

            return ValidateOptionsResult.Fail("Invalid");
        }

        return ValidateOptionsResult.Success;
    }
}
```

- I add the options to the appsettings.json file

.

```
"MyOptions": {
  "DirectoryPath": "C:\\Logs",
  "FileName": "log.log"
}
```

- In the library I extend the service collection to register the options validation

.

```
public static class IServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddMyLib(this IServiceCollection services) =>
        services.AddSingleton<IValidateOptions<MyOptions>, MyOptionsValidator>();
}
```

- In the main project I setup the logging part. First I create a new file logger. Since this one can't be a "normal" service and won't be added to the DI container I simply expect the needed options in the constructor

.

```
internal class FileLogger : ILogger
{
    private readonly string fullLogFilePath;

    public FileLogger(string logDirectoryPath, string logFileName)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(logDirectoryPath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(logDirectoryPath);

        fullLogFilePath = Path.Combine(logDirectoryPath, logFileName);
    }

    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        if (!IsEnabled(logLevel))
            return;

        using StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fullLogFilePath, true);
        streamWriter.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.Now}] [{logLevel}] {formatter(state, exception)} {exception?.StackTrace}");
    }

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel) => logLevel != LogLevel.None;

    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state) => null;
}
```

- To serve this logger I added a provider

.

```
internal class FileLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
{
    private readonly IOptionsMonitor<MyOptions> myOptionsMonitor;

    public FileLoggerProvider(IOptionsMonitor<MyOptions> myOptionsMonitor)
    {
        this.myOptionsMonitor = myOptionsMonitor;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
    {
        MyOptions myOptions = myOptionsMonitor.CurrentValue;

        return new FileLogger(myOptions.DirectoryPath, myOptions.FileName);
    }
}
```

- and extend the logging builder to add the file logger

.

```
public static class ILoggingBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void AddFileLogger(this ILoggingBuilder loggingBuilder)
    {
        loggingBuilder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider, FileLoggerProvider>();
    }
}
```

- As you would do in a Web API project I added a startup file to configure all the options and setup the services

.

```
internal class Startup
{
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMyLib();

        IConfigurationSection myOptionsSection = configuration.GetSection("MyOptions");
        services.Configure<MyOptions>(myOptionsSection);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder)
    {
    }
}
```

- For the last part I updated the Program file to this

.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging(loggingBuilder =>
            {
                loggingBuilder
                    .ClearProviders()
                    .AddConsole()
                    .AddEventLog()
                    .AddFileLogger();
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webHostBuilder =>
            {
                webHostBuilder.UseKestrel().UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            });
}
```

- You should get a System.AggregateException because of a circular dependency

Comment: Honestly, I had a similar problem for logging from the Program.cs code, before the services get configured.  I did end up using Serilog to having a logger availible earlier in my code. So I would solve it by getting the logger in a different way for the startup code like the validator and use the loggging service in the rest of the application

Comment: But isn't this illogical? If your options are invalid for logger, why would you try to log something? You could not log because your log options are invalid. If you want to log that your logger is configured incorrectly, you have to utilize some other logger that does not depend on any options at all, say for example - log in Windows Event Log

Comment: Agree with Nikita: "validator gets injected a logger instance to log validation errors if some occured" doesn't make sense when you inject that same logger you are validating. Just throw exception if options are invalid.

Comment: The fact that you are getting this exception is a clue, as NikitaChayka and Evk have mentioned, that you're trying to do something that doesn't make sense.

Comment: its basically saying ur logger can not also depend on a logger...., as that would mean that.... that logger would need a logger and sooooooo the cycle goes. remove the logger from within ur logger or as Nikita says make it depend on a different logger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed @Olaf Svenson's recipe for replicating the problem, which I have been able to replicate. I then tried @Martin's approach by making the `MyOptionsValidator` aware that it needs a `ILoggerFactory` but it still resulted in a circular dependency scenario (somehow).

I think there should be a way to log unhandled exceptions so that you don't need to log anything in your `MyOptionsValidator` but rather let it return a failure result which would result in an exception being thrown and that be logged instead. But for Worker Services this seems to be an issue? Let's assume we cannot do this, then look at the solution I provided below...

(UPDATE: You actually don't even need to do this below but it was a cool challenge nonetheless. Don't log within your Validator. This will prevent the unnecessary complexity. The normal unhandled exception logging process will kick in and actually log to the other loggers when your logger's config is invalid. Super simple and very effective. Now you can have all kinds of loggers take care of this concern for you.)

My thinking is that this problem is a complicated one and you need to move the complexity to the DI space where it belongs (since that's where all the components and dependencies are wired up that caused this to happen) so that any new Validator that you write will not have to be aware of this "circular dependency" problem of a given logger that you want to inject.

The one method I tried to address this with is to create a Fall-back logger. Now I'm in no way saying my approach is the defacto standard but it solved the problem and since it should only run once (since the `MyOptionsValidator` is setup as a singleton) you don't have to worry about any performance hits at runtime.

I changed the code that did this:

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddMyLib(this IServiceCollection services) =>
            services.AddSingleton<IValidateOptions<MyOptions>, MyOptionsValidator>();
```

To do this:

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddMyLib(this IServiceCollection services) =>
            services.AddSingleton<IValidateOptions<MyOptions>, MyOptionsValidator>(
                sp => new MyOptionsValidator(CreateFallback<IValidateOptions<MyOptions>>()));

public static ILogger<T> CreateFallback<T>()
{
    return LoggerFactory.Create(x => x.AddConsole()).CreateLogger<T>();
}
```

I am not sure how to inject a secondary `ILoggerFactory` using the .NET Core DI infrastructure. Maybe you could create a wrapper class and use an embedded instance of a LoggerFactory and then resolve that wrapper class everywhere you would like to use the Fall-back logger?

You have to setup a separate `LoggerFactory` instance to make sure you don't expose the `FileLogger` that can cause the problem. This does mean that your `AddMyLib` extension method would have to move somewhere where you are happy to pull in the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` package (and whatever logger package you wish to use in the process) unless you can make use of the wrapper solution I mentioned (using an abstraction of course).

So if your app is incorrectly configured, it will log the configuration error and the app will stop running since the `MyOptionsValidator` causes an exception to be raised.

[image: Logging the configuration error and displaying the exception]

But if your app is correctly configured...

[image: App is running happily]

Answer (score 1):

Look at this from a logical standpoint: if your logging configuration is invalid, you can't log using that configuration, period, so there's no use to introduce the circular dependency: the loggers created by your `ILoggingFactory` won't be able to log, because of the invalid configuration.

So if you want to *log that your logging configuration is invalid*, look at how other logging frameworks do that. First, decide for yourself whether you consider this a fatal state. Do you not want your application to run in this scenario? In other words: should an invalid logging configuration prevent the program from running, or should it run and not log?

Either let it throw an exception, so the configuration error leaks to the console or event log, or do it as log4net and the likes: have a default, fail-safe logging mechanism, like logging to console or an opt-in logger-error-logfile.

I'd opt for the latter, so let your logger fail silently, and add an optional setting like `logErrorLogFile`, to which your logger configuration can log its log configuration error, and have a separate DI flow for that (or hardcode it).

And if *that* fails, for example when the file is not writable, it can throw an exception. Or not.

Comment: @Dandré I _think_ that exceptions thrown during Windows Service startup are logged to the event log automatically, but can't find a source for that this quickly.

Comment: Sorry, I second guessed myself which is why I deleted my comment. I tested what you explained and I got my answer. So when I ran my service with the necessary credentials it did log that exception to the Windows Event logs using the standard logging config provided

Comment: @Dandré thanks for verifying that! Of course when a service is started through the Service Control Manager, there's no user-readable console.

Comment: hence why its so important that the Console is not the only output option :) I need to log to Windows Event Logs or some other logging center such as Elastic Search or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments of @Nikita and @Evk it is also illogical and I would not recommand to do it in this way.

But if you have the need and its not possible to change your logic/design here maybe you could try using:

```
public class MyOptionsValidator : IValidateOptions<MyOptions>
{
   private readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;

   private ILogger _logger;
   protected ILogger Logger 
   {
       get 
       {
          if(_logger == null)
          {
              _logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger(GetType());
          }
          return _logger;
       }
   }

   public MyOptionsValidator(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
   {
       _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
   }

   public ValidateOptionsResult Validate(string name, MyOptions myOptions)
   {
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myOptions.DirectoryPath) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(myOptions.FileName))
       {
           Logger.LogWarning("Invalid");
           return ValidateOptionsResult.Fail("Invalid");
       }
       return ValidateOptionsResult.Success;
   }
}
```

Now the `MyOptionsValidator` constructor injects just the `ILoggerFactory` to create a `ILogger`. And whenever the `Validate(...)` is called and the `ILogger` is needed the `Logger` will be created lazily by the `_loggerFactory` once.

Example can be found here: [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JpOwEc)

[image]

Comment: Hi Martin. Would you mind trying out your solution using Olaf Svenson's step-by-step instructions. I tried it with your workaround and it still gave a circular reference exception. Just want to see if you would get a similar outcome. Though I understand your solution to the problem and it makes sense but I don't know if somehow it will still end up causing a circular reference issue in the normal setup. I tried that especially by taking the config values out to test the actual scenario where you incorrectly configured your app.

Comment: @Dandre: I tried it in the updated [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/509fuk) and there it was working. I updated it to use also IOptionsMonitor<T> not the simplified code.